# Hyperlink text disappears based on combo box value on continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a bit of an unusual problem (or at least I think it's unusual). I have a continuous form that shows certain records based on a query that updates after I change the value in a combo box. I have a "View All" hyperlinked text box so that I can switch to seeing all of the records when I want to, but have discovered it only *appears* when I have selected a combo box value that has records. For example, if I want to find records assigned to Joe Shmo and there is one record assigned to him, the hyperlink appears. If I want to find records assigned to Susie Seashell and she has none assigned to her, it disappears. The catch is that if I click on the area of the screen where the hyperlink ***should*** appear, it still works as expected-- there is just nothing visible that would lead you to click there. The text field's visibility is on, and I even tried coding in a txtfield.visible=true and it did nothing. Any help would be appreciated!

**Note:** The hyperlink control source is ="View All". Not sure if that matters or not.

All of the VBA code used on this form is below:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cboFindNotice_AfterUpdate()
getSearchResults

End Sub


Private Function getSearchResults()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim errMsg As String
    '== Sets value of string 'sql'

    sql = "SELECT tblNotice.ID, tblNotice.noticeSEIFnoticeNumber, tblNotice.noticeJurisdiction, tblNotice.noticeDueDate, tblNotice.noticeTitle, " _
        & "tblAnalysts.[analyst_lName] & "", "" & [analyst_fName] AS Expr1, tblNotice.noticeStatus" _
        & " FROM tblAnalysts INNER JOIN tblNotice ON tblAnalysts.ID = tblNotice.noticeAnalyst" _
        & " WHERE tblNotice.noticeAnalyst LIKE '*" & Me.cboFindNotice & "*'" _
        & " ORDER BY tblNotice.noticeDueDate"


    '== Displays records based on query
    Me.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.Form.Requery
End Function

Private Sub noticeSEIFnoticeNumber_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNoticeDetails"
    [Forms]![frmNoticeDetails].Controls("txtControlField").Value = Me.Controls("ID").Value
Call Forms.frmNoticeDetails.txtControlField_AfterUpdate
End Sub


Private Sub txtViewAll_Click()
    Me.cboFindNotice.Value = ""
    Call cboFindNotice_AfterUpdate

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds to me like one of Access's many bugs. I would have guessed that Me.Repaint after Me.Form.Requery might work, but docs say "completes any _pending_ screen updates", but I'm guessing the problem is that Access is somehow discarding paint requests for the textbox, so there's no pending requests to complete.  You could still try that to see if it forces a full repaint.  If that doesn't work, perhaps to the end of getSearchResults, add `txtViewAll.Visible = False` followed by `txtViewAll.Visible = True` or some other code that forces an update of txtViewAll appearance.

Comment: Hm. I really thought Me.Repaint was going to work, but I got nothing. This small problem is turning into quite a little bugger.

Comment: I believe the hyperlink's control source should be blank and the "View All" text should be in the default value property of the textbox.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Such a simple solution.